Why eprosima::fastcdr::FastCdr isn't used in rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c and how would I integrate or use FastCdr
I'm working with ros2_jazzy, and I've noticed that the rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_cpp package uses of eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr for serialization and deserialization but don't see any usage or mention of eprosima::fastcdr::FastCdr.
My query are

Is the eprosima::fastcdr::FastCdr class not used in ros2 jazzy version?
Is there any configuration to enable FastCdr class usage?
If I can configure FastCdr, is it always for a fixed data type or does it depend on the message used for serialize/deserialize?

